# Scrolling DIV between fixed header/footer

Tags: html, css

i would like to use a website with fixed header/footer and a scrollable div in between.

Only the div in the middle should scroll, no scrollbar for the whole site (that's why body overflow is hidden).

[My attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/q8zqt29u/2/) so far:

```css
#container1 {display:block;padding-top:60px;overflow-y:scroll}
#container2 {display:none;padding-top:60px;overflow-y:scroll}

body{overflow:hidden}
```

The scrollbars are shown but too much on the right, also they are not scrollable?

PS: Unfortunately the switching between the DIVs don't work at JSFiddle, don't know why...

Comment: use `overflow: auto;` http://jsfiddle.net/q8zqt29u/3/

Comment: @Petroff: This just shows the scrollbar for the whole site... i need the scrollbar only for the middle div and right beside the div.

Comment: you are right. Jashem Qolami answer is correct +1.

Answer (score 3):

If the header and footer have explicit heights, it could be achieved simply by positioning the middle DIV absolutely and using `top`/`bottom` offsets with the respect to the height of the header/footer.

Then we can add `overflow-y: auto` to the middle DIV — [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8zqt29u/4/):

```css
#divLinks {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 460px;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#divLinks {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

#page{height: 100%;width:480px;margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}
#header{position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;right: 0;z-index:998;height:25px;background:#5f5f5f}
#bottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;left: 0;right: 0;z-index:999;height:40px;background:#5f5f5f}
```

```html
<div id="page">

 <div id="header">Header</div>
 
 <div id="divLinks">
 
  <div id="container1">First<br><br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br></div> 
  <div id="container2"> second<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1</div>

 </div> 
 
 <div id="bottom"><a href="#">First Page</a> - <a href="#">Second Page</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works... but only for one div. You removed my #containers ;) #divLinks is just the main container for #container1 and #container2 ... THEY should be scrollable.

Comment: @WeekendCoder Ah.. okay, however `#divLinks` is not just *the main container for #container1 and #container2* but the middle DIV between header/footer :-) I can't imagine how the layout should look like if the `#divLinks` shouldn't have scrollbars. When contents of the `#divLinks` are higher than the viewport, how can we see the overflows?

Comment: @WeekendCoder Also I'm not sure if I've understood: `You removed my #containers` since I didn't remove any element from the markup.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to use fixed elements, like this:

```
<header>Header</header>
<main>Content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

and

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 2em;
}

main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 4em);
    background-color: green;
    y-overflow: auto;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 2em;
}
```